# The equivalent of wxYield in Cocoa

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, wxwidgets

I'm new to MacOS programming. I'm using Objective-C with XIB interfaces to develop Mac Apps.

I'm making an app that zips and unzips files/folders. I've also implemented a progress bar to show the progress of the task.

But, when the user drops a big file to compress the app freezes, the progress window never gets displayed but the logs are working fine though.

I remember when I was using wxWidgets, in a case like that I'd have to use `wxYield()` to process the events and update the ui and everything would be fine.

So, what's the way to do this thing on Cocoa?

Comment: @BasilsBogiatzhs, why not get wxWidgets sources and check? OTOH - is your current program uses threads? Why does it freezes?

Comment: Or [Simple progress bar is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944268/simple-progress-bar-is-not-updating)

Comment: @Willeke, I don't think the question is about updating the progress bar. The application just freezes when it tries a really big file and it needs time to handle the events.

Comment: @BasilhsBogiatzhs, like I said - grab the wxWidgets sources and check how the library does it on Cocoa.

Comment: @BasilhsBogiatzhs, just grab them and grep for it. Most likely its in the generic code. If you can't find it - compile the library, modify the minimal sample and run it under debugger. Its an easiest solution.

Comment: @Igor the question is about updating the UI when the main thread is processing a big file. The Cocoa way to do this is to process the big file on a secondary thread so the main thread has time to handle events and update the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it using [@Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke)'s suggestions.

I'm executing the `zip_close` function on a different thread letting the main one handle the UI updates & events.

Also when the progress callback gets emitted, I'm updating the UI by accessing the main thread (making changes to the UI from another thread will give warnings).

Thank you both @Igor and @Willeke for helping out!